# Class Cast Exception when using spring API for Unmarshalling xml

Tags: spring, apache-camel, unmarshalling

**Below is the error message :**

```
INFO  [integration.ordXX.controller.PaymentOrder] (http-127.0.0.1:7070-1) ......Request Received for the ordergetPackagesToScan : [Ljava.lang.String;@6472d5b3
2017-06-20 14:57:02,989 ERROR [integration.ordXX.controller.PaymentOrder] (http-127.0.0.1:7070-1) Error in submit method: java.lang.ClassCastException: integration.ordXX.request.Order cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
                at integration.ordXX.controller.PaymentOrder.submit(PaymentOrder.java:72) [classes:]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
                at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.j
```

**Here we are using spring API :**

```
//JAXBElement<Order> element = (JAXBElement<Order>) convertor.unmarshal(ordXXReqMarshaller, orderXml);
Order ord=(Order)JAXBIntrospector.getValue(ordXXReqMarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(orderXml))));
//order = element.getValue();
```

We are trying to unmarshall the xml object with above code but we are getting exception on top of code.

When we tried to achieve the same with camel route it is successful.

Can someone help me please?

**Camel route used**

```
from("read from file")
  .unmarshall()
  .jaxb("package")
  .process(new TestProcess())
  .to()
```

Comment: what is this `JAXBIntrospector.getValue(ordXXReqMarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(orderXml))));` resolved to?

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBIntrospector.html#getValue-java.lang.Object-) say "_Returns Object. Get the element value of a JAXB element. Convenience method to abstract whether working with either a javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement instance or an instance of @XmlRootElement annotated Java class._"

Comment: The issue is the our xsd root element Tag is not proper after correcting that unmarshall is successful.

Comment: Pass second argument as your class and try -   ordXXReqMarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(orderXml)),Order.class)